# a proof that involves Lebesgue measure and Lebesgue outer measure in $R^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a question regarding the proof of Theorem 2.25 in here: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m206/measure_notes.pdf

specifically I was wondering how the inequality

$\mu(G \setminus F) \le \mu^{*}(G\setminus A)+ \mu^{*}(A\setminus F)$

is established. (Here we have  $G \supseteq A \supseteq F$)

I know that a measure $\mu$ would satisfy monotonicity, so if $A \subseteq B$, then $\mu(A) \le \mu(B)$. So since here I have $G \supseteq A \supseteq F$, then I know I have $\mu(G\setminus F) = \mu((G\setminus A) \cup (A\setminus F)) \le \mu(G\setminus A) + \mu(A \setminus F)$ (but all these here involved Lebesgue measure instead of Lebesgue outer measure and the only inequality or equality that involves both that I know of is $\mu^{*}(G) \le \mu(G)$, also I know that $\mu^{*}(K) = \mu(K)$ if K is a rectangle).

So is it possible to know how that inequality is established? specifically how the lebesgue outer measure $\mu^{*}$ is involved in there to come up with that inequality above?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If $\{I_n\}$ and $\{J_n\}$ are sequences of intervals covering subsets $X$ and $Y$ of $\mathbb R^n$, then both sequences together cover $X\cup Y$, so $\mu^*(X\cup Y)\leq \sum \mathrm{vol}(I_n)+\sum\mathrm{vol}(J_n)$.  Taking the infima over all such sequences of intervals you get $\mu^*(X\cup Y)\leq \mu^*(X)+\mu^*(Y).$

This shows that Lebesgue outer measure is subadditive, one of the properties generally required of something called an [outer measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure).  Actually the stronger property of countable subadditivity holds; [here's a proof](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/countable-subadditivity-of-the-lebesgue-outer-measure) (for $n=1$ but it generalizes) on Mathonline.

This subbaditivity of $\mu^*$ for a union of two sets is all that is used in the  inequality in question.  (Note that $\mu$ and $\mu^*$ are equal where $\mu$ is defined, i.e. on measurable sets, by definition of $\mu$.)

---

Later I looked at the notes you linked to.  See theorem 2.4 in the section introducing Lebesgue outer measure, and definition 2.10 where Lebesgue measure is introduced.

Comment: Hi Jonas, but could you explain how that inequality is established? i.e. $\mu(G \setminus F) \le \mu^{*}(G\setminus A)+ \mu^{*}(A\setminus F)$  ?

Comment: @john_w: If $Z= X+Y$ then $\mu^*(Z)=\mu^*(X\cup Y)\leq \mu^*(X)+\mu^*(Y)$ (a special case of the more general theorem cited from your notes).  If $Z$ is measurable then $\mu^*(Z) = \mu(Z)$, by definition of $\mu$.  See definition 2.10 (I missed that you weren't clear on the definition of $\mu$).

Comment: Hi Jonas, I think you explain very clearly. Thanks. Also I have another question. When Lebesgue Outer Measure is defined on a set of measurable set, is it true that the countable sub-additive will become countable additive? So if I have a set of subsets say $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n,...$, an I have an Lebesgue Outer Measure say $k^{*}()$, then among those $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n,...$ above, if I only take those that are measurable say $A_{a1}, A_{a2}, ... A_{an},...$, then the Lebesgue Outer Measure $k^{*}()$ will suddenly become a Lebesgue Measure say denoted as $k()$and Countable Additivity will hold?

Comment: What I mean is the definition of $k^{*}$ which is the infimum of the measure of a countable union of set that contains a set A stays the same, but some how $k^{*}$ will have the property of countable-additive holds for pair-wise disjoint sets?  whereas previously, countable-additive might not hold even for pair-wise disjoint set?

Comment: @john_w: For pairwise disjoint measurable sets, countable additivity of Lebesgue measure does hold. In other words, Lebesgue measure is a measure (see definition 1.9).  This is what Theorem 2.9 shows.

Comment: HI Dr. Meyer, could you help to comment on one more question specifically this one here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385293/theorem-of-regularity-of-lebesgue-measurable-set  it is based on the same notes, where I am little confused about a theorem.